# Are every prime (except 2,3,5) divisor of some of 10^n+1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Referring to [Is it true, that every prime (except 2) can be found as a divisor of enough long series of 1-s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733807/is-it-true-that-every-prime-except-2-can-be-found-as-a-divisor-of-enough-long) , I have the same question.

I have the intuitive hyptohesis, that every prime can be found as a divisor of at least one of 11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, ...

Is it true? My try to prove that didn't work in the related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prime $31$ is not a divisor of any number of the form $10\cdots01$.

Indeed, a prime $p$ divides $10^n+1$ iff the multiplicative order of $10 \bmod p$ is even (and equal to $2n$). But this does not always happen.  For $p=31$, we have 
$10^{15} \equiv 1 \bmod 31$ and so the multiplicative order of $10 \bmod 31$ is not even, since it has to divide $15$. (The order is actually $15$.)

Comment: Yes, 31, 37, 41, 43, 53, ... aren't divisors of $10^n+1$.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A186635.